# Альтернатива .delay()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Насколько я понимаю, .delay() не работает с .addClass и .removeClass, как можно реализовать подобие вот такой конструкции:

```
$('.element_1').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('element_2').delay(1000).removeClass('element_2'); 
});
```

Чтобы при клике добавлялся класс, а затем удалялся и при повторном клике на элемент происходило тоже самое. .toggleClass в этом случае не подходит.

Суть в том, что после клика происходит CSS анимация через @keyframes.

Comment: Вам нужен `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Да, спасибо! Разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, получился следующий скрипт:

```
    $('.element_1').click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('element_2'); //Добавяляем класс элемнету
       setTimeout(function(){ // Устанавливаем задержку
            $('.element_1').removeClass('element_2'); //Удаляем элемент
       }, 1000); //1000 - одна секунда
     });
```

Comment: Нет, так нельзя. Если у вас будет несколько элементов с классом .element_1 - то класс исчезнет у всех, а не только там где был добавлен. Если пользователь будет часто кликать - полезут визуальные баги.

Comment: Вам надо сохранить `$(this)` в локальную переменную: `var $this = $(this)` и потом использовать его.

Comment: Можно немного подробнее?

Comment: Да куда уж подробнее-то?

Comment: Пример скрипта, например. Я пытаюсь похожую задачу решить, где другим элементам удалить/добавить надо, не выходит. Например есть div в который вложен input и label, когда input .focus лэйблу добавляется класс, когда .focusout удаляется.